# New to JavaScript but my function works wrongly in Firefox

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm just getting into JavaScript and so far enjoying the logic behind it but I have an issue with Firefox. Basicly I'm generating my JavaScript from within a PHP function and its a NON SECURE pin code auth script.

So my PHP creates a call that passes variables pin number included, when called a modal popup with pinpad opens and the user inputs 4 digits, the pinpad `onclick` function adds the digits into a password field and after 4 clicks it compares it to a hidden field on the pinpad form, if it matches it calls another generated function to complete the success action, if no match pinpad frame turns red and a bypass button is enabled or they can try again.

This all works fine in Chrome, Opera and even IE but in Firefox it calls the success function after 4 digits even if they don't match the pin field.

Why could this be? Below is the function, but please remember I'm new so it could possibly be better written.

```
function add(text) {
    var TheTextBox = document.pinform.elements['pin'];
    var pincheckbox = document.pinform.elements['pincheck'];
    var sidbox = document.pinform.elements['sid'];
    TheTextBox.value = TheTextBox.value + text;
    if (TheTextBox.value.length == 4) {
        if (pinform.pin.value == pinform.pincheck.value) {
            var pinn = document.getElementById('sid').value;
            eval('pinpass' + pinn + '();');
        } else {
            document.getElementById("bypass").innerHTML = "Bypass";
            document.getElementById("bypass").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("calc").style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            TheTextBox.value = '';
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you escaping some of the quotes?

Comment: Whenever you see "eval", go back to the original task. (But that may be a different question.)

Comment: Please validate your syntax before posting a question. Check http://www.jshint.com/ or http://www.jslint.com/.

Comment: (Nit: If it was merely invalid syntax, it wouldn't work in IE/chrome either, although it could be caching quirks masking the behavior. I suspect it's from a PHP string or otherwise, but .. missing context.)

Comment: escaped quotes are being used because this script is being generated from within a php function so it is echoed php

Comment: You can replace `eval('pinpass' + pinn + '();');` with `window['pinpass' + pinn]();`, which will make the code more efficient, and avoid some possible horrible code injection vulnerabilities, although you should probably refactor more to avoid the need to use even this.

Comment: im using eval because higher up in the function i generate a xhtml post (pinpass) this will be pinpass1 or pinpass2 etc depending on the user id that was clicked, I could think of no other way to call the function so i used eval()

Comment: I've fixed the indentation and unescaped the quoting so that your code is more readable.

Comment: rjmunro it seems you have inadvertently solved the issue. i updated the script to use your "safer method" and walah its fixed.
Many Thanks.

Comment: oops, no its not. i refreshed my firefox and entered wrong pin to find it worked but upon retesting just now ive found its wrong again. so it must be caching some how as mentioned earlier, any idea how to fix?

Comment: Is anything showing in the Firefox Javascript console? Try putting the code as output by your PHP on http://jsfiddle.net/ along with the HTML to recreate the problem, then posting a link to that here.

Comment: i cant use jsfiddle as its dynamicly created code for the most part,
i can provide an in the wild link to view the sorce of the pages if that would help

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer by trial and error as usual lol.
i need to add document. in front of pinform.pincheck.value and pinform.pin.value

Thanks for the help offered.
Nick

```
if (TheTextBox.value.length == 4) {
    if (doucment.pinform.pin.value == document.pinform.pincheck.value) {
        var pinn = document.getElementById('sid').value;
        eval('pinpass' + pinn + '();');
    } else {
```